# screen resolution wrong -> black screen

Tags: 12.04, installation, resolution, screen, aspire-one

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my Acer Aspire One (netbook) with the help of wubi. The installation went fine, but after logging in my screen resolution was wrong. Because of that the desktop and all the windows were displayed incorrectly. Also, because of this I couldn't change the resolution to a normal setting. I rebooted and now the display is black. I can here the boot process is going normally and after the beep I can log in correctly (but I can't see a thing).
How can I change the resolution to a normal setting?

Regards,
Marco

**PS:** the screen isn't broken, the netbook has a dual install and in Windows Vista everything is working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previous similar questions seems to be quite old for this new release. Nevertheless you should consider to take a look at the answers to this question: [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) of which I suggest you to give a chance to [**this specific answer**](https://askubuntu.com/a/162076/9598) which made my day when I faced something similar in the past in 12.04.1 LTS no matter if you have or not an nvidia/ati gpu.

Additionally, you may wish to have a look on this website: [**X/Troubleshooting/BlankScreen/Wiki**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/BlankScreen) in which you may find a solution for several sceneries which includes but not limits to [**Problem: System is Completely Unresponsive, with Blank/Black Screen**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/BlankScreen#Problem:__System_is_Completely_Unresponsive.2C_with_Blank.2BAC8-Black_Screen)

Please inform how are you managing this issue in order to follow up your question.

Good luck!

Comment: First, thanks for taking the time to help me out! Second: I don't have a grub screen. I have the option Windows or Ubuntu and after I choose Ubuntu I can't get to the grub menu with shift. So, changing the grub menu is out. I looked at the solutions you mentioned and they all have in common that I must have access to my Ubuntu install. Should I try to get to my install with a Ubuntu live cd/usb?

Comment: Well, look... Last time I went into a major issue with the blank screen and to be honest I didn't find an answer soon, and I couldn't wait for it (check this open question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/187466/ubuntu-12-04-1-wont-boot-after-fixing-blank-screen-and-low-graphics-mode-issu) so I decided to reinstall (as you suggest). I am having a dual boot Win7/Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS and at the very moment of the new Ubuntu's install I was prompted what I wanted to do. So I chosen "something else", erased the partitions and made it manually so that the new system installed with no problems.

Comment: So I kept dual boot and a GRUB, everything working pretty fine. Nevertheless, your case may be different as you used wubi for the first install, after which the results may be different than mine. If you choose to run into the risk of reinstalling from scratch, I suggest you to first backup all your important data and try it. Please feed us back with the details on how are you managing this issue and... Good luck!

Comment: My Acer Aspire One is very reluctant to receive Ubuntu! First, my disk in Windows refuses to shrink so that I can install Ubuntu. Second, gparted on Ubuntu Live also doesn't want to change the disk, so there's no room to install.

Comment: My Acer Aspire One is very reluctant to receive Ubuntu! I've removed my wubi Ubuntu install. Then I made myself an usb based Ubuntu live cd. I can't use the setting nomodeset because it's not available during install from 12.04 live usb. Furthermore, I can't create enough room on my hard drive. In windows the disk refuses to shrink (only 85 Mb while there is 200 Gb free space). Also gparted on Ubuntu live can't make changes to this disk. Grrr, it's frustrating...

Comment: Victory at last!! I did these steps to solve my problem: 1. updated my ubuntu live usb with update manager. This solved the screen problem. 2. I used (free) EaseUS Partition Master (www.partition-tool.com) to resize my disk so that Ubuntu has room to install. 3. I installed Ubuntu with this manual: http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/05/17/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7/

Comment: Good to know that you succeeded. :) Just for the record: when I face these problems with resizing partitions I suggest to defrag the disk and fix windows based disk errors previous to resizing. The majority of the problems when resizing is related to defrag. And there are several other tools that allow you to force resizing, just make sure you first defrag or your data will be hard to reach thus delaying in the disk. Thank you for the feedback. Good luck!